# Grafana value_string not in alert template anymore

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager, grafana-variable, grafana-alerts

I am using Grafana for alert messages based on prometheus datasource conditions.
Since update to Grafana 10 the alerts do not contain the `value_string` anymore. My understanding is that the value_string is the data underlying the conditions.

The problem is that I cannot see in my alert mails, from which kubernetes namespace the alert comes from.

Any ideas how I can enable the `value_string` again?